# Illegal modifier for the local class error

Tags: java

So i'm still new to Java so this could be really dumb, But I Couldn't find an answer so here we go! At the beginning of my code I'm trying to declare the class, Simply with "public class robot{}" however, its giving me the error "Illegal modifier for the local class ____; only abstract or final is permitted". Everywhere I look on the internet, it says not to call it a static class, BUT I'M NOT!!! This could be something really dumb that I Don't know yet since I'm still new. Please Help! Here's my code:

---

```
public class Robot
{
private String dir = "N";

public Robot(String dir)
 {
    this.dir = dir;
 }
}
```

Comment: What else do you have in your Robot.java file? Your code is correct if it is only what you have in Robot.java

Answer (score 1):

> *Illegal modifier for the local class ____; only `abstract` or `final` is permitted*

The "keyword" to note in that error message is **local**.

The error message is a result of this clause in the Java Language Specification [§14.3 Local Class Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.3):

> It is a compile-time error if a local class declaration contains any of the access modifiers `public`, `protected`, or `private` ([§6.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6)), or the modifier `static` ([§8.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1)).

A [local class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html) is a class declared **inside a method**.

Move the class to it's own `.java` source file. Or remove the `public` keyword, because it makes no sense to declare it public anyway, when the class is only in scope inside the method.

Answer (score 0):

Only one class can be public in one java file and if you are including  main method in the same file then only that class can be declared public.

Now solution to your code : remove public keyword only